# java stack incomplete in JNI invoking

Tags: java, java-native-interface, stack

I invoked libhdfs interface of hdfs in my c application, pstack provides part of stack information of hung thread as follows:

`#0  0x000000302b808b9f in pthread_cond_timedwait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 ()`

`#1  0x00007f3eac557666 in`enter code here`os::PlatformEvent::park ()`

`#2  0x00007f3eac547279 in ObjectMonitor::EnterI ()`

`#3  0x00007f3eac546e42 in ObjectMonitor::enter ()`

`#4  0x00007f3eac62e1eb in ObjectSynchronizer::slow_enter ()`

`#5  0x00007f3eac62e0e4 in ObjectSynchronizer::fast_enter ()`

`#6  0x00007f3eac31dbf8 in InterpreterRuntime::monitorenter ()`

`#7  0x00007f3ea7929b98 in ?? ()`

`#8  0x000000041261f958 in ?? ()`

`#9  0x00007f3ea7929b64 in ?? ()`

`#10 0x0000000000000003 in ?? ()`

`#11 0x0000000411fff290 in ?? ()`

`#12 0x0000000053d37980 in ?? ()`

`#13 0x000000040c9ac640 in ?? ()`

`#14 0x0000000053d379e0 in ?? ()`

`#15 0x000000040c9aca08 in ?? ()`

`#16 0x000000040d1a1698 in ?? ()`

`#17 0x000000040c9ac650 in ?? ()`

`#18 0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()`

Top seven level stack seem to be c code of synchronizer in jvm, **here is the question, how can I get
detailed java stack instead of "??",** should it be java symbol talbe or something?

Answer (score 0):

Your debugger will need debug symbols for the JVM itself. I don't think Oracle supplies them for their Java distribution, but it's usually not a problem with OpenJDK. OpenJDK is the basis for Oracle Java, so using it instead is not a big leap into the unknown.

Your stack trace looks like gdb, so I'm going out on a limb and guess you're working on a Linux system. In that case, check your distribution's package database for OpenJDK and a debug symbol package -- most (certainly all mainstream distributions) have it.

For example, Debian (and Debian-derived distributions like Ubuntu and Mint) have packages `openjdk-8-dbg` and `openjdk-7-dbg.` Red Hat/Fedora calls them `java-1.8.0-openjdk-debuginfo`. I don't know which distribution you're using, but if you search the package database for "openjdk" and "debug", you'll probably find it.